# Smallest positive integer that when divided by 23 has 20 as remainder and 34 remainder when divided by 41.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The textbook that I'm using explicitly says to solve it without using the Chinese remainder theorem(or modular arithmetic for that case).

Any help/hint would be appreciated.

Edit: Upon reviewing the question, the book resolution does in fact use the CRT despite it imposing the restriction(The error has already been reported to the professor). Nevertheless user's u/Ilovemath answer still stands and is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, what technique does your book recommend then? I guess you could always just brute force it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sequence of numbers leaving remainder $34$ when divided by $41$ is $$34, 75, 116.....$$ which is an arithmetic progression with common difference $41$.

Similarly, the sequence of numbers leaving remainder $20$ when divided by $23$ is $$20, 43, 66....$$ which is also an arithmetic progression with common difference 23.

We need to find the smallest number common to both sequences.

If that number is the $mth$ term of first sequence and $nth$ of the second, $$34+(m-1)41=20+(n-1)23$$
Hence, we have $41m=23n+4$.
Or $46m=23n+5m+4$.

From here, we observe that $5m+4$ should be divisible by $23$.

Smallest such $m$ is $13$.
Hence the answer is $34+(13-1)41=526$.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), it tells you exactly when such systems of congruences have solutions (and gives a formula for the solution).

Comment: OP explicitly mentioned that use of CRT is disallowed.

Answer (score 0):

No chinese remainder theorem: Your problem can be stated:

$\begin{align*}
  x
    &\equiv 20 \pmod{23} \\
  x
    &\equiv 34 \pmod{41}
\end{align*}$

This is $x = 23 a + 20 = 41 b + 34$ for some $a, b$. Consider this last equation modulo 41:

$\begin{align*}
  23 a + 20
    &\equiv 41 b + 34 \pmod{41} \\
    &\equiv 34 \pmod{41} \\
  23 a
    &\equiv 14 \pmod{41} \\
  a
    &\equiv 25 \cdot 14 \pmod{41} && \text{since $23 \cdot 25 = 575 \equiv 1 \pmod{41}$} \\
    &\equiv 22
\end{align*}$

The value of $b$ is obtained similarly.